# How to import a Unity WebGL Project to my owl website

Tags: c#, html

I made a unity webGL project and I am wondering how to import the game over to my own website.

When I open the GL, it opens a localhost link. So an iframe wont work.

Answer (score 0):

Your have to upload it to your web server folder.

For local testing, you can init your local web server via xampp or mamp, those are free web server software. Then place your webgl build into the public folder for web browser.

Or, you can also host it via github, if you don't want to slowdown your own website.
The format will be like this:

- Example Project url: https://github.com/username/project-website-link
- Example Web url: https://username.github.io/project-website-link/

You may also change your root path in your git project->settings->pages

this is just an example of my use case:

- https://github.com/frozenmistadventure/demofmpoints
- https://frozenmistadventure.github.io/demofmpoints/